# Allow only floating values to be inputted, maximum value being 100.00

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, floating-point

There's a HTML input text field, say for price, for which it is required that it's maximum price could be 100.00, minimum could be 0.00 .

Jquery code to allow used this range is as follows:

```
$('#price').keypress(function(event) {
if(event.which == 8 || event.which == 0){
    return true;
}
if(event.which < 46 || event.which > 59) {
    return false;
    //event.preventDefault();
} // prevent if not number/dot

if(event.which == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
    return false;
    //event.preventDefault();
} // prevent if already dot
});
```

But this allows users to put in `12345` or `1235`  or `123.5`  etc.
Corresponding HTML for the text box is :

```
<input type="text" name ="" value="" id="price" maxlength="5" min="0.01" step="0.01">
```

If `type="text"` is changed to `type="number"`, the applied Jquery doesn't work on it.

How can we allow user to input just the float numbers from 0.00 to 100.00 and ONLY up to 2 decimal places. eg : 4.32, 9.99, 99.99 etc.

Comment: Your values are based on the unicode numbers of each keypress and not the number represented by text? ex. 0=48, 1=49, a=65, z=90,[ENTER] = 13,etc.

Comment: you can at least set the max attribute on your input field  `max="100.00".` That changes the attribute `maxlength="6"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="price">
```

**js**

```
$('#price').mask('Z00.00', {translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[1]/, optional: true}}});
```

[fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/112g/om8wjpy9/1/)

Comment: any method without the use of external libraries ?

Comment: it should be : $('#price').mask('ZZ.00', {translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[1]/, optional: true}}});

Comment: in this case user can enter only numbers like 11.xx

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (it'll put 100 in the input if entered value is bigger):

```
$("#price").blur(function() {
    $(this).val(parseFloat(Math.min($(this).val(), 100)).toFixed(2));
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xLhqygp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

```js
$('#price').keypress(function(event) {
if(event.which == 8 || event.which == 0){
    return true;
}
if(event.which < 46 || event.which > 59) {
    return false;
    //event.preventDefault();
} // prevent if not number/dot

if(event.which == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
    return false;
    //event.preventDefault();
} // prevent if already dot
});
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseFloat(value) < min || isNaN(value)) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseFloat(value) > max) 
        return 100; 
    else return value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name ="" value="" id="price" maxlength="5" min="0.01" step="0.01" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 100)">
```